# <tr> aparece al principio por más que la ponga al final

Tags: html

extrañamente por más que agregue un  tr sea donde sea, se agrega por arriba de la tabla y no entiendo por qué, alguien lo sabe? (Es el  tr que está ultimo solo por encima del  /table, el  /body y el  /html) Ya probé ponerlo en diferentes partes del código pero siempre sale en ese mismo lugar, puede se que esté bugeado o algo por el estilo?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Objetivos</h1>


<table class="table">
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------- -->
    <tr>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        @foreach($objetivos as $obj)
            <th>{{$obj->nombreObj}}</th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        @foreach($fechas as $fecha)
            <tr>
                    <td>{{$fecha->fecha}}</td>
                @foreach($fecha->objetivos as $tiempoObjetivo)
                    @if($tiempoObjetivo->tiempo > "01:00:00")
                        <td style="color:green;">{{$tiempoObjetivo->tiempo}}</td>
                    @else
                        <td style="color:red;">{{$tiempoObjetivo->tiempo}}</td>
                    @endif

                @endforeach
            </tr>

        @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endif
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------- -->
    @if($objetivosCount > 0)
        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'route' => 'objetivos.store']) !!}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {!!Form::date('fecha')!!}
                    </td>
                    @foreach($objetivos as $obj)
                        <td>
                            {!! Form::time('tiempo[]') !!}    
                            {!!Form::hidden('obj_id[]', $obj->id)!!}
                        </td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">{!!Form::submit('Agregar datos de hoy')!!}</td>
                </tr>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endif
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------- -->
    <tr>
        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET', 'url' => '/createObj']) !!}
            <td>{!!Form::text('nombreObj')!!}</td>
            <td>{!!Form::submit('Agregar objetivo')!!}</td>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </tr>
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------- -->
<tr>Hola</tr> <!--This is the line // Esta es la linea-->
</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**No sé si el error viene por parte del HTML o Laravel**
PD: Tuve que borrar partes del código porque sino Stacoverflow no me dejaba publicar la pregunta

Comment: En principio, le falta la etiqueta td `<tr><td>Hola</td></tr>`. Pero tienes otras inconsistencias ahí, indenta tu código para ver más fácil que abras y cierres cada etiqueta y directiva de blade. También cualquier ide decente te va a marcar esos errores de html.

Comment: ¿Como lo indento?

Comment: Lo puedes indentar a medida que lo escribes. Si no depende qué ide uses, seguramente tiene la opción.

Comment: Es que no entiendo a que te refieres con indentar, no es acaso ponere las sangrías al código? Porque en ese caso el código ya está indentado

Comment: Claro, me refiero al sangrado para distinguir los bloques de código y etiquetas. En el código que pusiste verás que tienes descolgado un `</tr>` y un `@endif`. Tampoco está indentada justamente la etiqueta que marcas como "esta es la línea". En fin, solo era un consejo para que sea más fácil detectar esas inconsistencias y errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr>
    <td>Hola</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Vaya, que error más torpe jajajajaja... Te agradezco